# How can I turn off autocomplete in whole community?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, soql, community

How can I turn off autocomplete in whole community ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Salesforce settings do not control the autocomplete functionality, but this can be changed by customizing your browser settings.

To Disable Auto-Fill on Google Chrome Browser

> 1.Open Google Chrome.
>
> 2.Click the three lines beside star on the top right and click settings.
>
> 3.Click Show Advanced settings.
>
> 4.Uncheck the Enable Auto-fill to fill out web forms in a single click.

To Disable Auto-Fill on Safari Browser

> 1.Open your Safari browser.
>
> 2.Click Safari in the program menu and select Preferences in the drop-down menu.
>
> 3.Click on the Autofill tab in the Preferences window.
>
> 4.Click on each of the check boxes next to the autofill options to deselect them, turn off the autocomplete for each option.

Refer the [Disable auto-completion for all fields in Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000317749&type=1) for other browser settings